# Next and Previous Button - Breaking my mental state

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have been trying for days to get a next button to work in an excel VBA form.  I have a form with multiple items, including some combo boxes.  I have tried repeatedly to get the code to work so I can add a next item button and a previous item button.  I want these buttons to search the tables data and show the previous set of data and the next set of data.  Ultimately so these can be edited once the buttons work.  The previous button takes me to the first set of data but wont cycle and the next button gives me an object error in my row names (txt.name.text = cells(currentrow,1) code.  Any help or assistance with getting these buttons to work would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub cmdnext_Click()
  Dim lastrow As Long
  Dim currentrow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

currentrow = currentrow + 2

txtname = Cells(currentrow, 1)
txtposition = Cells(currentrow, 2)
txtassigned = Cells(currentrow, 3)
cmbsection.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
txtdate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5)
    txtjoint = Cells(currentrow, 7)
txtDAS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8)
txtDEROS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 9)
txtDOR.Text = Cells(currentrow, 10)
txtTAFMSD.Text = Cells(currentrow, 11)
txtDOS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 12)
txtPAC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 13)
ComboTSC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 14)
txtTSC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 15)
txtAEF.Text = Cells(currentrow, 16)
txtPCC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 17)
txtcourses.Text = Cells(currentrow, 18)
txtseven.Text = Cells(currentrow, 19)
txtcle.Text = Cells(currentrow, 20)

If currentrow = lastrow Then
MsgBox "Why wont this work"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim currentrow As Long

 If lastrow = currentrow Then
   MsgBox "this doesn work yet"
 End If

 currentrow = currentrow - 2

 txtname.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1)
 txtposition = Cells(currentrow, 2)
 txtassigned = Cells(currentrow, 3)
 cmbsection.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
 txtdate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5)
 txtjoint = Cells(currentrow, 7)
 txtDAS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8)
 txtDEROS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 9)
 txtDOR.Text = Cells(currentrow, 10)
 txtTAFMSD.Text = Cells(currentrow, 11)
 txtDOS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 12)
 txtPAC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 13)
 ComboTSC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 14)
 txtTSC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 15)
 txtAEF.Text = Cells(currentrow, 16)
 txtPCC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 17)
 txtcourses.Text = Cells(currentrow, 18)
 txtseven.Text = Cells(currentrow, 19)
 txtcle.Text = Cells(currentrow, 20)

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you why `CommandButton6_Click` won't work. The initial value for `currentrow` is zero and you then subtract two and use that as your cell row index.

Using `Cells(-2, something)` is *not* likely to end well.

---

And, now that I look more closely, you have the same issue with `cmdnext_Click`. Because `currentrow` starts at zero every time this function runs, and you add two to it, you're *always* getting `Cells(2,something)`.

---

I think you probably need to find a way to make `currentrow` persistent so that it's not initialised to zero every time you click a button.

Answer (score 0):

Something more like this:

```
Dim currentrow As Long '<< you should set a value for this
                       '   when your form first loads

Private Sub LoadRow()
    With Sheet1.Rows(currentrow)
        txtname = .Cells(1)
        txtposition = .Cells(2)
        txtassigned = .Cells(3)
        '... etc etc
        txtcle.Text = .Cells(20)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub cmdnext_Click()
    If currentrow < Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row Then
        currentrow = currentrow + 2
        LoadRow
    Else
        MsgBox "Already at end"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrev_Click()
    If currentrow > 2 Then
        currentrow = currentrow - 2
        LoadRow
    Else
        MsgBox "Already at top"
    End If
End Sub
```

No need to repeat all that loading code.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it and it doesn't give me any errors but the previous button only goes back to the top row.  I am trying to get it to cycle through all of the rows. Any advice?

Comment: Yes - try debugging, and see where it's going wrong.  You may need to add some code when the form loads, to position `currentRow` wherever you want your first loaded record to be.

Comment: Thanks got it to work.  Now to work the update button.